# Programmatically switching tabs in a Tab Control

Tags: c#, wpf, tabs, tabcontrol

I am wondering how to switch to a different tab within a tab control.

I have a main window that has a tab control associated with it and it directs to different pages.  I want to switch to a tab from an event triggered within a different tab.  When I try to use TabControl.SelectedIndex I get the error "An object reference is required to access non-static, method or property 'MainWindow.tabControl'

Here is my code declaring the TabControl from the MainWindow and trying to switch to it from a different tab.

```
<TabControl Name="tabControl" Margin="0,117,0,0" SelectionChanged="tabControl_SelectionChanged" Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="Black">
        <TabItem x:Name="tabMO" Header="MO" IsTabStop="False">
            <Viewbox x:Name="viewMO" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both">
                <local:ManufacturingOrder x:Name="mo" Height="644" Width="1322"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem x:Name="tabOptimize" Header="Optimize" IsTabStop="False">
            <Viewbox x:Name="viewOptimize" Margin="0,0,0,0" Stretch="Fill" StretchDirection="Both">
                <local:EngineeringOptimization x:Name="Optimize" Height="644" Width="1600"/>
            </Viewbox>
        </TabItem>

</TabControl>



private void dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var cellInfo = dataGrid.SelectedCells[0];
        var content = (cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item) as TextBlock).Text;
        var r = new Regex("[M][0-9]{6}");

        if (r.IsMatch(content.ToString()))
        {
            MainWindow.tabControl.SelectedIndex = 4;
        }
}
```

I have tried switching this to a private static void and received the same error.

I have also tried the following code, creating an instance of MainWindow, and there is no errors but when I run the code the selected tab doesn't change on the screen.  But if I use a MessageBox to view the Selected Index, than I see my changed tab Index.

```
private void dataGrid_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var cellInfo = dataGrid.SelectedCells[0];
    var content = (cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item) as TextBlock).Text;
    var r = new Regex("[M][0-9]{6}");

    if (r.IsMatch(content.ToString()))
    {
        MainWindow frm = new MainWindow();
        frm.tabControl.SelectedIndex = 4;
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks like WPF, not WinForms.

Comment: Winforms: tab.SelectedTab = tabpagename

Comment: @LarsTech You are correct,  I was looking at tags for similar questions and it slipped through, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your main problem is that you do not have easy access to your MainWindow and all of its children from within your `ManufacturingOrder` or `EngineeringOptimization` UserControls.  Which is normal. There are a few ways around this.  A simple one, which violates some MVVM principles, (but you're doing that anyway, so I don't think you'll mind) is to retrieve the instance of your `MainWindow` object:

```
//Loop through each open window in your current application.
foreach (var Window in App.Current.Windows)
{
  //Check if it is the same type as your MainWindow
  if (Window.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
  {
    MainWindow mWnd = (MainWindow)Window;
    mWnd.tabControl.SelectedIndex = 4;
  }
}
```

Once you retrieve the running instance of your MainWindow, then you have access to all its members.  This has been tested as well as possible without access to your specific custom UserControls and instances.  But it's a pretty standard problem and solution.

You were on the right track with your last bit of code in your question, but you were creating a 'new' instance of your MainWindow.  You have to retrieve the current running instance, not a new instance.